# HTML time input field minimum and maximum attributes not working for minutes

Tags: html, angularjs, input, time

So Im using angular to create a simple mobile app and within a section of html i have this:

```
<input id="timeSelected" type="time" min="{{minTimeToPresent}}" max="{{maxTimeToPresent}}" ng-model="date.time" class="time-input" ng-change="checkTheSelectedTime()"/>
```

This is my really simple "time picker" and it works really nicely, I have dynamically given the element a min and max as you can see and the min and max works for the 'hours' portion of the time and even removes hours that lie outside of the range from the scroll wheel inside the app (when tested on a phone of course) but for some reason it does not do the same for the minutes.

Interestingly my ng-change function is not triggered if you select a time that is out of the range in regards to minutes, so if i have a max of **"20:30:00"** for example and pick the time **"20:31"** the ng-change is not triggered at all, but if i pick **"20:30"** it is triggered.

So it is acting as though it knows the min and max, but what I want in the first place is for the incorrect **MINUTES** to be removed from the selectable scroll wheel too, like the hours.

Please help, thanks!

**Additional Details...**

- The dynamically set times are in this format: e.g. "21:30:00"
- I set the min and max values before the DOM has loaded so that I can be sure that the correct values are going to be used.

Comment: Using the HTML5 validators for min and max, this will not be possible. These only validate on form submission. It could not limit the minutes, otherwise it would prevent users from selecting a valid time if it was less than your max.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I have found that will accomplish this without writing something custom yourself is using [UI bootstrap Timepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker)

You can specify a min and max and it will restrict the user from changing it in the input. It validates input in real time. Sounds like those are your requirements.

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H11sEeFIAFJy5R9x2ETV?p=preview) demo from their site that I modified showing the min and max validation. You must specify min and max in the controller code in date format.

**HTML**

```
 <uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian" max="max" min="min" ></uib-timepicker>
```

**JS**

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours( 2 );
d.setMinutes( 30 );
$scope.min = d;

var d2 = new Date();
d2.setHours( 11 );
d2.setMinutes( 0 );
$scope.max = d2;
```